# MVC 3 WebGrid.Table footer parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I've been trying to use the WebGrid to display a footer row that contains totals for the grid. So far, I've been appending the totals row to the result set, which partially works. My issue is that when you sort, the total row also gets sorted, which I don't want. Also, when you add paging in the mix, the total row is in the last page.

I noticed that there is the method [WebGrid.Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webgrid.table%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) which takes in a parameter named footer of type System.Func. I'm thinking this might allow me to set the footer row, but there doesn't seem to be any documentation out there on how to use this. How can this be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `footer` parameter expects a Razor template just like the `format` parameter of a `WebGridColumn`:

```
var grid = new WebGrid(Model);
var cols = new List<WebGridColumn>();
//add some columns
var table = grid.Table(columns: cols, footer: @<text>Footer</text>);
....
....
@table
```

This will render the word "Footer" in a `tfoot` element that has a single `td` with a `colspan` equal to the number of columns in the `List<WebGridColumn>`. If you want to align footer text under certain columns, you can pass a full HMTL table in to the Razor template delegate and style it accordingly to achieve the desired alignment eg:

```
footer: @<table><tr><td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td><td>footer</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>
```

Alternatively, you can use jQuery to create a footer:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var html = '<tfoot><tr><td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td><td>footer</td><td>&nbsp;</td>';
        $('table').append(html);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: So, the table that you are rendering for the footer in the second example, that would be rendered in the tfoot>td as well?

I've seen the jQuery way, but I think it's rather "hacky." It's such basic functionality in my mind.

Comment: No - if you do not specify a footer in the WebGrid.Table method, no <tfoot> is rendered so the jQuery example doesn't result in a nested table. The <tfoot> is appended to the rendered grid (assuming it is the only <table> element on the page.